# mongoose filter by objects in array

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following mongoose schema:

```js
var MySchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    attributes: [ {name: String, value: Schema.Types.Mixed} ]
});
```

It's unfortunate, but the clients will dictate what the attributes will be, so it's impossible to know what they will be upfront.

I'm trying to write a generic search function that will filter results based on attribute.name='x', and possibly attribute.value='y'(although my example below has left values out). Any tips on how to write such a method?

```js
let filter = ['name', 'attributes.name=height', 'attributes.name=superpower'];

function search(filter) {
   //This  needs to be fixed
   const mongoReply =  await myModel.find({}, 'attributes.name');
}
```

UPDATE:

So this is code that seems to be working for me. I'm still trying to do further testing to make sure it's behaving as expected.

```
const mongoReply = await cuk.aggregate([
            {
                $match: {$and: [{'attributes.name' : 'color'}, {'attributes.name' : 'superpower'}]}
            },
            {
                $project: {
                    attributes: {
                        $filter: {
                            input: '$attributes',
                            as: 'attribute',
                            cond: {
                                $or : [ { $eq: [ '$$attribute.name', 'name'] },
                                    { $eq: [ '$$attribute.name', 'crypto_length'] }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        ])
```

Answer (score 0):

The query should look like this:-

```
await MyModel.find({ "attributes.name": "x", "attributes.value": "y" })
             .select(["attributes.name", "attributes.value"])
```

You can read more about select here https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-select

Comment: so that will find me the record(s) where the name is x, and the value is y. But if there are other attributes, like height=10, but i only want to return name and value, but not height...how can I filter/select on just name/value?

Comment: Please check the updated answer. You can append .select() to the query to include or exclude values. In order to exclude some field just add "-" in front of it like .select("-attributes.height")

Comment: So in this case my attributes are {name: string, value: Mixed}. So there is no attributes.height. It's attributes.name=height. The select you have will still return height. It's as if i need that search in the select, but that doesn't seem to be valid syntax.